# Find the center of a sphere given 3 points in Powershell or Python

Tags: python, powershell

i need to come up with a script in Python or Powershell that will request 3 points on a sphere that look like these...

```
$p1 = 121021.7391,27709572.4368,-2369575.3890
$p2 = 746442.4255,27095391.7051,-2388765.7650
$p3 = 766543.7492,27435797.7212,-2571188.0087
```

Then I need it to output the coordinates of the center of that sphere.

I am not a math wizard nor a programming wizard.  My strength is Powershell but not sure that the necessary math functions exist.  Python I feel would be an easier transition but I am not overly familiar with it.

I believe that I need to find the center of these 3 points which I have done with this...

```
[double]$x1 = $p1.split(",")[0]
[double]$y1 = $p1.split(",")[1]
[double]$z1 = $p1.split(",")[2]

[double]$x2 = $p2.split(",")[0]
[double]$y2 = $p2.split(",")[1]
[double]$z2 = $p2.split(",")[2]

[double]$x3 = $p3.split(",")[0]
[double]$y3 = $p3.split(",")[1]
[double]$z3 = $p3.split(",")[2]

$centroidx = ($x1 + $x2 + $x3)/3
$centroidy = ($y1 + $y2 + $y3)/3
$centroidz = ($z1 + $z2 + $z3)/3

$centroid = "::pos{0,0," + $centroidx + "," + $centroidy + "," + $centroidz + "}"
```

So this should give me the center of the triangle.

Now I believe that I need to find the perpendicular line to this point and then find the equidistant point on either side of the plane and one of these will be in or near the center of the sphere and the other will be equal distant outside the sphere.

What I do not know is how to do any of that in powershell or python.  Any help with the coding from here would be appreciated greatly!  Is there a library or function already written in either of these languages that already does this?

Comment: Seems like something you could do by creating a system of equations in 3 variables (you know that each point is the same distance from the center) and solving it with [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve).

Comment: I appreciate your guidance.  Unfortunately I need more detail than this.  I am not a python person at all.  I only suggested it as I know it has a ton of libraries and is commonly used for this.  I am looking into it now though, thanks